# Is it possible to responsively adapt html content vertically using CSS?

Tags: css, flexbox

With CSS it is easy to adapt responsively the content of an html page, when window is rescaled horizontally, like in example A.

[image]

Now with new flexbox features, I am trying to figure out if it is possible to adapt the content when you rescale window vertically, like in example B. (using flexbox or anything else!)

[image]

Comment: what do you mean "adapt" ? just resizing? or what?

Comment: I believe he's asking "How do I make a horizontally scrolling site? Can I do it with flexbox?" So all elements fit the window height, but overflow can scroll to the right.

Comment: I would say to just let it overflow.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what i mean: an horizontally based site. But also I would like the content adapt vertically: for example if my browser window height has more than 900px and my pictures are 300x300, there will be 3 rows. Now if the windows height is between 600 and 900px, there will be only 2 rows. And if the windows height is less than 600, there will be only one row. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems pretty straightforward with flexboxes. Set a max-height on your flex container and use

```
flex-flow: column wrap;
```

to line op your flex items in columns.

Comment: Well, turns out it was not that difficult, thank you! In case someone need a more complete solution here it is: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7c6f0a28/)